# elastic search client using R packages

Tags: java, r, elasticsearch, cran

I am using `elastic search` as data store. In my project i need to analyze the `elastic search` data using `R`. In `java` i did these operations using es client. But i couldn't find any packages in `R` that support `elastic search` operations. 
I have tried using `RCurl` packages like this:

```
count <- fromJSON(getURL("http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_count"))
```

But this is not i want. Is there any packages in `CRAN` or other repositories that perform `elastic search` operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been working on an elasticsearch R client here https://github.com/ropensci/elastic

There's a bunch of examples here https://github.com/ropensci/elastic#quick-start

It is alpha software though, so expect changes. I'll try to get alot of work done on it next month.

Would love pull requests.

Comment: sorry y'all, still not much progress on the R client, but hoping to get more work done soon...

Comment: The `elastic` package is now on CRAN http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elastic/index.html  - would love any feedback